# What is the origin of this alternate ending to Captain Tsubasa?

Tags: captain-tsubasa

A while back, I stumbled upon [this video](http://youtu.be/ol1-my6VeZE) which shows an ending to the Captain Tsubasa series. However, I quickly found out that it is not the real ending.

In this video (which is in Spanish, I could not find the same video in English), we see a young Tsubasa playing with a football, which eventually ends up on the road, leading to Tsubasa being run over by a truck. It then jumps to a scene where Japan is playing Brazil in what seems to be a final. Finally, it jumps to a scene where we see an older Tsubasa lying in an hospital bed.

At the beginning of the video, a subtitle goes by saying something similar to:

> This is the closest to another ending in which Oliver (Tsubasa) has no legs in the hospital.

---

I ended up finding [another video](http://youtu.be/W18R3PbRiss) (also in Spanish) that elaborates on the story.

It explains that on the first chapter of the original manga, Tsubasa is hit by that same truck from the other video, but since he has a football, the impact is absorbed by it. He then starts to think of the football as his friend, and so the story we know unravels.

The video then states that in the final against Brazil, after Tsubasa scores a goal, the scene jumps to him waking up in the hospital and hugging his mother, telling him that they had won. The video states that if we look close enough, we will notice Tsubasa has no legs, because he really lost them in that accident, and is just waking up from a coma, having imagined all of the storyline. The video even states that there is a theory that this might have been part of the original plan by the author, since the word 'dream' is present in many of the titles, basically claiming that this is the original ending to the series.

---

All the information regarding this alternate video seems to be in Spanish, and I have not found much relevant info in English. The [few English sources I found](http://knowyourmeme.com/forums/meme-research/topics/11348-the-true-super-campeonescaptain-tsubasa-ending-creepypastafan-fiction) state this is fan-made. I tend to lean toward that possibility, as the one proposed by that last video seem pretty farfetched.

Whichever may be the case:
**What is the exact origin of this alternate ending?

Was it really supposed to be the original ending?

Or if it is fan-made, where did it originate? When was it first seen?**

---

<sup>I have not seen much of the series. The little I have seen was when I was a kid, and from a Portuguese dubbed version. So I know basically nothing about the storyline of the series.</sup>

Comment: The trope of ending has some relation to the ending for the American medical drama series *St. Elsewhere*, where the autistic boy imagined autistic boy imagine the six seasons of the show.

Answer (score 6):

I remember looking into this a while back, but never found where the theories about this 'true ending' originally surfaced.

The reason you see so much information about it in Spanish though is because Captain Tsubasa was one of the first Anime to ever air on TV (at least in Mexico), and it was extremely popular at the time. The theory probably surfaced there, and once it got into the internet it became an 'urban legend' of sorts.

But yeah, the alternate is purely fan-made. As far as I know the manga is still running.